# Edit component property onClick Next.js

Tags: javascript, material-ui, next.js

Am new with Next.js seeking your support to explain how to pass a new value for a property of a component. I used Material-UI library for styling.

While am trying to change open property for a drawer component it always show for me [TypeError] `open` is read-only.

```
const drawer = (
  <SwipeableDrawer open={drawerOpened}>
    <div tabIndex={0} role="button">
      {sideList}
    </div>
  </SwipeableDrawer>
);

const handleClick = e => {
  drawerOpened = !drawerOpened;
  drawer.props.open = drawerOpened;
  e.preventDefault();
};

const Index = () => (
  <div className={styles.root}>
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          className={styles.menuButton}
          color="inherit"
          aria-label="Menu"
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={styles.grow}>
          Example
        </Typography>
        <Button color="inherit" style={{ right: "0px", position: "absolute" }}>
          Login
        </Button>
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
    {drawer}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where you declared the `drawerOpened` variable. 
Either way, once you swapped the value of `drawerOpened`, the prop for `drawer` has changed, and there is no need to tamper with `drawer.props.open`:

```
const handleClick = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  drawerOpened = !drawerOpened;
};
```

Another thing to point out, ideally `Index` should be a React Class (not a functional component) which has `state`. `drawerOpen` would be stored in `state` and passed down as a prop to `drawer`. `handleClick` would `setState` of `drawerOpened`:

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  state = {drawerOpened: false}

  handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      drawerOpened: !prevState.drawerOpened
    }))
  };

  render() {
    return <div className={styles.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            className={styles.menuButton}
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="Menu"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            <MenuIcon/>
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={styles.grow}>
            Example
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit" style={{ right: "0px", position: "absolute" }}>
            Login
          </Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <SwipeableDrawer open={this.state.drawerOpened}>
        <div tabIndex={0} role="button">
          {sideList}
        </div>
      </SwipeableDrawer>
    </div>
  }
}
```